# Consider a wire of length $L$ with linear charge density $\lambda$.

Tags: electromagnetism

I am a new student, I know the concepts of electric field and it is difficult for me to solve this exercise. Could you help me with this exercise?

Consider a wire of length $L$ with linear charge density $\lambda$. Calculate the electric field at the points indicated in the following figure and make a diagram outlining the electric field at each point.

[image]

For practical purposes do $L = 1 m$, $\lambda = 1 c/m$. Scale the result by $9 \times 10^{-9}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearly, for each point you’ll have to integrate _something_ along the length of the wire. Can you at least work out what that _something_ is for some specific point?

Comment: @amd I understand perfectly, but I don't know how to proceed from it.

Comment: When in doubt, go back to definitions. Write down an expression for the electric field due to a point charge at some position on the line, then substitute the charge due to an “infinitesimal” piece of the line into that expression to get your integrand.